# Karate API: responseTime not passed to calling feature

Tags: karate

We are using a wrapper feature to do a bunch of logic and only have the API call in another feature.

- A.feature: API call only
- B.feature: get the cookie, build the payload, call A.feature passing cookie and payload, get the results data back.

> def resp = call read('file:A.feature') arguments

I can get everything from the response of A.feature within B.feature by using **resp.response.**, and I can get responseStatus by calling **resp.responseStatus**.

However, I cannot get the responseTime neither calling **resp.responseTime** or **resp.response.responseTime**.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I would think responseTime behaves the same as responseStatus

Answer (score 1):

ok, found this one as well: I just needed to define a variable in A.feature as follow:

```
def time = responseTime
```

And then call that variable in B.feature from the result:

```
resp.time
```

Comment: yes, refer open issue: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2094